# how to set postgresql 9.6.2 to autostart when built from source on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos7

I've installed postgresql 9.6.2 from running from source.  I performed the `.configure`, `make` and `make install` commands, which installed the database perfectly.  I then installed the user, created the db using `createdb` command, and am able to log in locally to postgresql user to perform local sql queries.

My question is autostart.  How do I set it up so autostart is working?  the command `service postgresql restart` errors saying `no unit`.  I also tried `postgresql-9.6`, `postgresql-9.6.2`, `postgresql-962`, and several others to no avail.

how to I configure this?  Thanks.

Comment: Then use https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php. This is a much better approach than compiling your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using systemd, you can use the following service unit file (e.g., at /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
Documentation=man:postgres(1)

[Service]
Type=notify
User=postgres
ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /bd-01/pgsql/9.5/data -l logfile start
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```